# .htaccess or VirtualHost to block website from direct IP access, yet allow from URL only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have blocked direct access to my site using IP via virtual host. However, i am not able to use 403 error template defined as `error.php`

Since `error.php` is located at `/var/www/html/error.php`, so its blocked automatically and it errors out `Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

[image]

Below is my `000-default.conf`

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 1.1.1.1
        ServerAlias 2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Location />
            Require all denied
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So later i tried to achieve same using .htaccess (after removing the block from 000-default.conf ofcourse), I encountered same error. Can't select custom 403 template because path seems to be blocked. Below were .htaccess contents placed at `/var/www/html/`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^2001\:2001\:2001\:2001\:2001\:2001$
```

Running Apache/2.4.38

Comment: You will need to add an exception for your error document, access to that one you _want_ to allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it out. Sharing if it could help someone facing similar issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 1.1.1.1
        ServerAlias 2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001:2001
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Options FollowSymLinks
            <Files error.php>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </Files>
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```